# Windows form renaming form removed all control

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I’m new to c# and windows forms, but not programming. I have a windows form project I’ve been working on and I thought I might change the name from form1. When I did that I noticed that my form[design] completely reset. It was still running properly until I rebuilt the project. Does anyone know how to restore my original form design? It seems like all my controls still exist somewhere, when I add a button to the blank form it defaults it to button3.

Comment: What specifically did you rename, and how did you do it?

Comment: You see, when you create a form, visual studio make 3 files .cs, .design.cs and one file for resources, ir you change public partial class Form1 to public partial class MyForm on .cs file, but not change public partial class Form1 on design.cs the void inicitialize() lose, so in this void it&#39;s on the components are created